# Width of google chart

Tags: css, google-visualization

I have the following code to creategoogle charts:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
var options = {
        ....
      }; 
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ...
        ]);
var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('consumer_s1'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

In the documentation for BubbleChart, Google says "default-width: width of the containing element".
I have this container:

```
<div class="responsive" id="consumer_s1">
```

with

```
.responsive{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

But when I create the chart, in Firebug I see that Googlechart created these elements:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 200px;" dir="ltr">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" aria-label="Un grafico.">
    <svg width="400" height="200" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-label="Un grafico." aria-hidden="true">
      ......
```

Why the first div created has that value for height and width??

Answer (score 8):

Example:

```
function drawChart1() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
            ['Mushrooms', 3],
            ['Onions', 1],
            ['Olives', 1],
            ['Zucchini', 1],
            ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
            'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
            'width': 800,
            'height': 600,
            chartArea: {left: 0, top: 0, width: "100%", height: "100%"}
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

**BUT one important thing**: if loading of charts is going in hidden area, for example in tabs - size always fall to 400x200, so keep it in mind. In such case for correct initialization of charts use first click on that tab OR any special button with "drawChart1" action ...

Comment: Hi realmag777,
Your observation regarding chart behavior in hidden area is superb... it helped finding me my bug. But when I try to open accordion before drawing then value of X-Y axis are no more visible and even legends are not showing up properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with window resizing. My fix:

```
var container = document.getElementById("consumer_s1").firstChild.firstChild;
container.style.width = "100%";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have width in your GoogleChart options? Something like this:

```
var options = {
  ...
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  ...
};
```

You can force here the size of chart. I don't know if it works with %.

Comment: No, I don't have this in my options. I use % because I want it responsive.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't know.
You can try with some od this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593514/google-visualization-chart-size-in-percentage or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835742/get-a-google-chart-image-to-fill-the-width-of-a-div

Answer (score -1):

I resolved using.. http://codepen.io/shoogledesigns/pen/BfLkA

There are the html directives:

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="col-1-2">
<div id="chart_div1" class="chart"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-1-2">
<div id="chart_div2" class="chart"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the js code:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
function drawChart1() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
['2004',  1000,      400],
['2005',  1170,      460],
['2006',  660,       1120],
['2007',  1030,      540]
 ]);

var options = {
  title: 'Company Performance',
  hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
 };

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);
function drawChart2() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
['2013',  1000,      400],
['2014',  1170,      460],
['2015',  660,       1120],
['2016',  1030,      540]
 ]);

var options = {
  title: 'Company Performance',
  hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
  vAxis: {minValue: 0}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}

$(window).resize(function(){
  drawChart1();
  drawChart2();
});
```